# What are the advantages of jar (war) compression?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, compression

*You can skip the wall of text and go straight to the questions listed below, if you are so inclined.*

**Some background:**

I'm currently doing some work on a large scale, highly modular Spring application. The application consists of multiple stand-alone Maven projects which are built separately. When compiling the whole application, these projects are pulled in as dependencies and overlaid onto the resulting 'super WAR' file.

**The issue:**

The build process (shortly) described in the preceding paragraph works well, but is very slow, even when all dependencies are already compiled and can be fetched from the local maven repository.

Some simple testing reveals that build-time of the 'super WAR' is cut in ~half when jar-compression is turned off entirely, at the cost of a comparatively small (~10%) increase in file size.

This is no surprise, really, as the build requires all the dependencies to be built/compressed and later decompressed, overlaid, and then compressed again (as a huge, unified war file).

Adding to this, a fair few of the "sub-projects" are pure web applications which contain no Java code needing compilation (or compression) at all (only static resources).

**Questions:**

- What are the advantages of jar (war, really) compression, except for the (negligibly) reduced file size?
- In the case of Java EE or Spring web applications, are there other (performance) issues introduced when turning off compression entirely? I'd think it has the potential to help both build time and JVM-startup.

*Any suggestions on how to handle the build process of non-java applications with maven more efficiently are welcome as well. I've considered bundling them as resources, but am not sure how to achieve this while ensuring they are still buildable as stand-alone war files.*

Comment: I don't believe there are any further advantages to compression. It's more about archiving so that you can distribute a single file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is my suspicion as well. If this is the case, surely there's no real reason to waste CPU time doing compression when the difference lies in +- 10 MB of storage space used on a web server?

Comment: The size you are wasting depends on the size of the resulting war/jar file. This can be much more.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the sometimes negligible reduction in the file size and the simplicity of having to manage only one file instead of an entire directory tree, there are still a few advantages:

- Reduced copy time, as per this answer: https://superuser.com/a/360532/145340 I can also back this up by personal experience, copying or moving many small files is much slower than copying or moving an equally large single file.
- Portability: The JAR file format is clearly defined, leaving no room for incompatible implementations.
- Security: You can digitally sign the contents of a JAR file, ensuring the integrity and authenticity of the contents.
- Package Sealing: Enforce version consistency, since all classes defined in a package must be found in the same JAR file.
- Package Versioning: hold data like like vendor and version information.

Comment: Thanks for your input!

These are all (with exception of file size reduction) properties of the archive format, and not compression itself (which is what I am specifically asking about). To be more clear: I am considering the possibility of building the application and output as a war file _without_ using compression. All advantages (as listed by you) of the jar/war format itself will therefore be preserved, with exception of the reduction in file size.

Comment: Depending on the scope of your project, some or many of these properties could be beneficial for you in the long run. As for building a project as an uncompressed war, there might be disadvantages, but never having done so myself I don't know any of them.